# Form Submit Not Redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I'm setting up a test e-commerce site and the setup is nearly complete. I'm implementing custom Bitcoin Payment at the checkout but can't figure out why the submit button isn't submitting + redirecting. Basically you go through checkout (you can put in dummy data) and then a button comes up that says "Pay with Bitcoin" but the thing isn't redirecting me to another page (the page redirect is the expected behaviour upon form submission).

The store link is: https://ibex-swag-store-front.herokuapp.com/checkout

Here's the component:

```
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <form 
        class="ibexpay-container justify-content-center align-self-center"
        action="https://ventas.ibexmercado.com/ibexpay_ecommerce/api/v1/buttons/create" 
        method="post"
        target="_top"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="button_id" value="U8gxqShiGtS5Xp8yCihUST" />
        <input type="hidden" name="description" value="(IBEX E-Shop) shop transaction." />
        {/* <input type="hidden" name="amount" v-model="cartValueUsd" /> */}
        <center>
          <ibexpay-button button-id="U8gxqShiGtS5Xp8yCihUST" description="Custom Memo" amount="0.05" />
        </center>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ManualPayment
```

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated!

Comment: On the link you have provided, i was not able to find the FORM tag. and the code you have posted as well.

Comment: @Mehrwarz it's here in the code. On the link provided, you have to go through adding the contact info + delivery method before it shows the payment button.

Comment: You have other form tag opened above the STYLE tag. which is not required and is resets the resets the inputs, the button_id is not being sent to the server. remove the tage and the child form will send the data you will be redirected to the page which creates QR Code.

Comment: Hmm @Mehrwarz I removed this, but it doesn't seem to fix anything. Anything else you'd recommend?

Comment: add onclick="submit()" in the button to force the submitting. check the console for any error. Maybe there is some error on the JavaScript file with breaks the submitting operation.

Comment: maybe you can add `onSubmit` on your form and redirect it manually with `react-router`

Comment: @Mehrwarz thank you, this worked, much appreciated! Got a BTC address I can send some cash to?